# Non-Volatile object in C#

Tags: c#, state

I want to be able to maintain a count and a last accessed date across application loads for a web service polling application. I'm not too sure what the best way to do this is. I dont like the idea of storing that data in a database as I would have to create one specifically for the purpose. What other options do I have and are there any particularly nice ways of keeping application state between subsequent runs of the app?

Comment: A database is probably your best bet - what happens if your web-service needs to scale to more than one IIS instance, where would there be a logical place to store the data to be consistent?

Comment: I couldn't tell if his app is a client app that consumes a web service or an actual web server serving up the web service.

Comment: I agree with Shaun. There's also file writing or cache type of solutions, but if you ever want to run reports and get stats database is the way to go in my opinion. Maybe even consider storing the 2 pieces of data on the client side (if applicable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persisting data eh?  I suggest a database or file.
File solutions you can just [XML serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to a file and load it again when the app starts.

If the data is shared or might ever grow, then a database is probably the best solution.  You can find one that fits your need among the many free projects if you wish:

- couchdb
- mysql
- postgres
- mangodb
- membase
- sqlite
- etc

You could roll your own solution that doesn't involve a database, but most likely there is one that fits your needs and learning it would be useful beyond just the project at hand.

Comment: @Mehrdad: you can make your +1 meaningful by upvoting the answer ;-)

Comment: @AdamRalph: Oh shoot, I totally forgot lol, thanks for reminding me. xD

Comment: Im consuming a webservice, seems like most people think database. It kinda seems like the data doesn't really fit a table though. It kinda seems like nothing is quite the right fit for the problem which is why im wondering if theres another better option. Prehaps i should just bite the bullet and jam it into a DB

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to make a 'configuration' style table for your website, that simply has only a few rows and let's you store runtime information as needed.

Perfectly fine.

Comment: Not so much fear, i just feel like there **should be a better solution for the problem.  i would actually only have 1 row in the table (and only ever 1 row).

For example a property bag (persisted KeyValuePair such as that in SharePoint) would suit the data much better.